# What is the cmake catkin variable for the workspace root dir?

Tags: ros, catkin, include, header, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Catkin puts the headers from my custom messages from package1 in

```
~/ros_ws/devel/include/<package1>/
```

I want to use them when compiling package2. I am assuming that the CMakeLists.txt for package2 needs a line like

```
include_directories(
  ${<WORSPACE_ROOT>}/devel/include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

but I don't know the correct variable is for the workspace root, ie ~/ros_ws.

The other question is: is there a better way of doing than than manually specifying the top-level include dir?

Here are the CMakeLists.txt files:

ardrone_autonomy (project1) :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(ardrone_autonomy)

find_package( catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs image_transport sensor_msgs std_srvs tf camera_info_manager message_generation  )

#uncomment if you have defined messages or services
add_message_files( FILES
    matrix33.msg
    navdata_adc_data_frame.msg
    navdata_altitude.msg
    navdata_demo.msg
    navdata_euler_angles.msg
    navdata_games.msg
    navdata_gyros_offsets.msg
    navdata_hdvideo_stream.msg
    navdata_kalman_pressure.msg
    navdata_magneto.msg
    Navdata.msg
    navdata_phys_measures.msg
    navdata_pressure_raw.msg
    navdata_pwm.msg
    navdata_raw_measures.msg
    navdata_rc_references.msg
    navdata_references.msg
    navdata_time.msg
    navdata_trackers_send.msg
    navdata_trims.msg
    navdata_video_stream.msg
    navdata_vision_detect.msg
    navdata_vision.msg
    navdata_vision_of.msg
    navdata_vision_perf.msg
    navdata_vision_raw.msg
    navdata_watchdog.msg
    navdata_wifi.msg
    navdata_wind_speed.msg
    navdata_zimmu_3000.msg
    vector21.msg
    vector31.msg
)

add_service_files(
  FILES
  CamSelect.srv
  FlightAnim.srv
  LedAnim.srv
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include devel/include
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs message_runtime
  DEPENDS libsdl-dev
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)


find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS) 
set(SDK ARDroneLib/)
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/)
include_directories(${SDK} ${SDK}/FFMPEG/Includes ${SDK}/Soft/Common ${SDK}/Soft/Lib ${SDK}/VP_SDK ${SDK}/VP_SDK/VP_Os/linux )
add_executable(ardrone_driver src/ardrone_driver.cpp src/video.cpp src/ardrone_sdk.cpp src/teleop_twist.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ardrone_driver ${catkin_LIBRARIES} pc_ardrone avcodec avutil swscale vlib  sdk SDL )
```

mrl_ardrone (project2) :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(mrl_ardrone)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp std_msgs cv_bridge ardrone_autonomy )

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES mrl_ardrone
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs cv_bridge ardrone_autonomy
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  # This is super sketchy, there must be an automated way to do this
  /home/mike/ros_ws/devel/include/
  ${ROS_ROOT}
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)


## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable( tracker src/tracker/trackerMain.cpp src/tracker/tracker.cpp src/tracker/drone_controller.cpp src/tracker/PID.cpp )
 
# make sure configure headers are built before any node using them
add_dependencies(tracker ardrone_autonomy) 


add_executable( testMain src/tracker/testMain.cpp src/tracker/drone_controller.cpp src/tracker/PID.cpp )
add_dependencies( testMain ardrone_autonomy )

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
find_package(OpenCV)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(cv_bridge)
include_directories(${cv_bridge_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries( tracker
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${cv_bridge_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

target_link_libraries( testMain
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${cv_bridge_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

When I run

```
~/ros_ws $ catkin_make
```

I get:

```
Project 'mrl_ardrone' tried to find library 'ardrone_autonomy'.  The
library is neither a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile
project 'ardrone_autonomy'? Did you find_package() it before the
subdirectory containing its code is included?
```

which suggests to me that my problem is not with the include directory itself, but something more general with CMake not being able to find stuff. But I have no idea.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/95596/what-is-the-cmake-catkin-variable-for-the-workspace-root-dir?/) by [ounsworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/7771/ounsworth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2013-10-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All you have to do is:

```
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Catkin and genmsg will take care of including the correct folder in devel space or in install space. This is under the assumption that you have called the following before:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS package1)
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ounsworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/7771/ounsworth/) on 2013-10-29**:
I have 'include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})', when I do 'find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS package1)' I get:

Project 'project2' tried to find library 'project1'.  The
library is neither a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile
project 'project1'? Did you find_package() it before the
subdirectory containing its code is included?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-10-29**:
May be it helps if you would post the CMakeLists.txt files of both packages. I am just guessing that you export a library in package1 (in the catkin_package() call) which you don't have.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-10-29**:
It looks like I guessed right. Your project1 contains `catkin_package(... LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME} ...)` but you don't build any library with that name. Remove that line from your CMake file.

**Comment by [ounsworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/7771/ounsworth/) on 2013-10-29**:
Wow, ok. Problem fixed. Thank you very much!!